# Magento Duplicate Address Autocomplete

Tags: php, magento, autocomplete, magento-1.9

I'm seeing some weird behavior with autocomplete on chrome (and other browsers) on our Magento sites.

- We operate a Magento 1.9 website.
- When using autocomplete during checkout, the billing address street and street2 will both populate with the street address.
- I have tried this on multiple devices, multiple addresses, incognito, etc.

Now, looking at the code, the street and street2 inputs are both named `billing[street][]`. This *has* to be an issue, right?

I'm not sure how to fix this autocomplete issue since we're trying to manipulate browser behavior, but I'm fairly confident it has to do with Magentos input naming conventions. Is there a patch out for this?

Comment: `billing[street][]` is the correct name (the `[]` means it's an array and treated as such in the backend), so there is no patch. You'll have to adapt your autocomplete script

Comment: Ah gotcha about the array. There is no autocomplete script, though, just default chrome behavior. Any advice there?